# PHP Fatal Error: Class not found when loading URL

Tags: php

I have a strange bug at the moment in my web service I am coding.
When I am loading an specific url I get a success and error at the same time?

This is what I have in my index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'functions/lib.php';
require_once 'core/init.php';

// Ask for request URL that was submitted and define scriptPath. Explode content of REQUEST URL to evaluate validity.
$requestURL = (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "") ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']);
$scriptPath = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$requestURL = str_replace($scriptPath, "", $requestURL);
$requestParts = explode("/", $requestURL);
// Check for valid api version
$validAPIVersions = array("v1");
$apiVersion = $requestParts[1];

// If API Version not in valid API array return 404, else OK.
if (!in_array($apiVersion, $validAPIVersions)) {
    httpResponseCode(404);
    echo $GLOBALS['http_response_code'];
    echo "<br>" . "API Version not valid";
    exit();
}

// Check for valid API endpoint
$validEndPoints = array("tickets");
$endPoint = $requestParts[2];
if (!in_array($endPoint, $validEndPoints)) {
    httpResponseCode(404);
    echo $GLOBALS['http_response_code'];
    echo "<br>" . "Endpoint not valid";
    exit();
}

// get the endpoint class name
$endPoint = ucfirst(strtolower($endPoint));
$classFilePath = "$apiVersion/$endPoint.php";

if (!file_exists($classFilePath)) {
    httpResponseCode(404);
    echo $GLOBALS['http_response_code'];
    exit();
}

// load endpoint class and make an instance
try {
    require_once($classFilePath);
    $instance = new $endPoint($requestParts);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    httpResponseCode(500);
    echo $GLOBALS['http_response_code'];
    exit();
}
```

and this is the corresponding "Tickets.php"

```
<?php
echo "OK";
?>
```

In the last two rows of my index.php, I am loading the specific class (named in the URL). For testing purposes, I have an "echo "OK" in this file. And this is the result when I am loading the URL I need:

http://api.medifaktor.de/v1/tickets

```
OK
Fatal error: Class 'Tickets' not found in /usr/www/users/kontug/api.medifaktor.de/webservice/index.php on line 45
```

I get the OK I was expecting AND the error for the Class Tickets, that is not found. Line 45 is

```
$instance = new $endPoint($requestParts);
```

Can someone give me a helping hand?

Best
Sebastian

Comment: So if the Tickets.php file only contains `echo "OK";` then it has no class definition and `new Tickets()` will error (can't instantiate a class that hasn't been defined). It won't throw an exception to be caught by your `try/catch`, it will just break execution with an immediate 500.  That `echo` is really the only contents of `Tickets.php`?

Comment: Wow... I stared at that echo for at least 1h and did not see the missing class. Embarrassing... thanks! Now it works fine!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a class "Tickets" defined. After you load the `tickets.php` file, you are attempting to instantiate a class. Loading a file is not the same thing as defining a class. Within `tickets.php` (or some other included file), you need to define the class, like so:

```
class Tickets
{
    // some properties here
    private $endpoint;

    // some methods here
    public function __construct($endpoint)
    {
        $this->endpoint = $endpoint;
    }
}
```

If you're not sure how to construct classes in PHP, read the section in the manual on [classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.classobj.php).

Update: I added some example code within the class for version PHP5+.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following for your test, in the 'ticket.php' file add:

```
class Ticket {

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'testing';
    }

}
```

Then make sure you either `namespace` or `require` the file.